# Applying autoencoders for dimensionality reduction in audio: Why does this create a low-pass effect?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, autoencoders

I've been playing around with framing audio data and training a single-layer autoencoder to find a dimensionality-reduced form (say 128-sample frames to 32-dimension frames). When I test the audio after going through the encode/decode layers (trying both sigma and tanh activation functions for what it's worth), it appears to have a low-passed effect. Why might this be?

For reference, an FIR low-pass filter is just a moving average.

Comment: Autoencoders - a type of neural network - are a form of machine learning, and this question is about the math behind auto-encoders.

Comment: I disagree with the mods decision to close this. How is this unrelated to the topic of machine learning?

Comment: This will probably get a better answer to the [Signal Processing Stack Exchange](http://dsp.stackexchange.com).

Comment: The answer to this question could lead to an enhanced understanding of the nature of autoencoders and the class of functions they're likely to compute. It has therefore been closed.